# More than one port available in Arduino IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Jetson AGX Xavier, and in my Arduino IDE, there are dev/ttyUSB0, dev/ttyUSB1, dev/ttyUSB2, dev/ttyUSB3. I'm sure I connect Arduino in USB0, but I cannot download the code. The device is also correct. Even if I disconnect the Arduino, the available ports are the same.

When I googled it, it turns out the port should be only one. Like, should be only "dev/ttyUSB0". So it really confused me.

Comment: You can find what your serial port are with `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id`

Comment: Exactly what Arduino are you using? Is it genuine? Is it a Chinese clone?

Comment: If you're sure that you choosed the right port, try reinstalling the Arduino IDE. Maybe this will solve your problem. If it won't, try installing an older IDE.